# Is possible to synthesize diamond at relatively lower pressures (6 to 7 GPa vs 12 GPa)?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, diamond

Pure binderless nanopolycrystalline diamond  can be produced from graphite when the graphite is treated with more than 12 GPa pressure  and at least 2100°C temperature .

If we treated  graphite or  amorphous carbon  with a somewhat lower pressure of 6-7 GPa but  with  a very high temperature  of 3000°C - 3500°C , would these conditions be sufficient to convert graphite to diamond without use of a catalyst ?

Answer (score 1):

Chemical vapor deposition is used to produce diamonds at low pressure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_diamond#Chemical_vapor_deposition

Comment: thanks, but  I talking about HPHT treatment,  CVD is very very slow process.

Comment: @abduoman - "HPHT" stands for "high pressure". How can you talk about that process and ask for "low pressure" at the same time. At any rate - please clarify in your question that this is the process you want to know about. I think this answer addresses the question you posed. But if it's not what you wanted, you might want to modify the question.

Comment: @abduoman: 50-150 micron per hour (http://www.pnas.org/content/99/20/12523.full ) does not look "very very slow" to me.

Comment: @Floris: I talking about relative low pressure , not absolutely low.

Comment: @akhmeteli:  150 micron/hr when compared to a piece of diamond has 10 mm diameter & 10 mm length synthesized using HPHT treatment for no more than 30 min. I think HPHT win.

Comment: @abduoman - a 10x10x10 mm diamond would take about 60 hours to grow by CVD if akhmeteli's number is correct. For a 17 carat diamond (3.52 gram) that is really quite a reasonable time. What is your hurry? Nature took millions of years to do the same...

Comment: @abduoman: The "winner" depends on the application, e.g., "About a decade ago Chemical Vapor Deposition (CVD) diamonds began to appear in the gem diamond market.  The CVD method can produce diamonds in a lower pressure environment than HPHT, using a gas such as methane and a substrate to grow diamonds. Diamond composition can be controlled to create a single crystal form allowing the production of very clean colorless diamonds over one carat in size much more economically then HPHT."http://www.kitco.com/ind/Zimnisky/2013-06-19-How-High-Quality-Synthetic-Diamonds-Will-Impact-the-Market.html

Comment: @Floris: the HPHT treatment  at 15 GPa & 2400°C can produce binderless nano-polycrystalline within only few minutes with comparable hardness & higher toughness .

Comment: @akhmeteli: for mechanical application, the binderless polycrystalline  diamond  is better than very clean diamond.

Comment: @abduoman: As I said, it depends on the application; however, it is not obvious that HPTP is better than CVD for the application you mentioned. High pressure typically requires expensive equipment.

Answer (score 1):

According to the phase diagram of diamond (see for example http://files.umwblogs.org/blogs.dir/6093/files/2011/10/carbon_phase_diagram2.jpg) there is a region where diamond is stable and graphite is metastable, at pressures and temperatures in the range you are asking about:

[image]

Given the slope on the diagram, you would actually expect that this reaction is more thermodynamically favorable at lower temperatures... but the rate of the reaction is probably quite slow.

CVD is indeed the more common method for slowly growing diamond at lower temperatures. Getting these very high temperatures and pressures at the same time places enormous demands on the surrounding materials systems - which is why natural diamond tends to be formed "under a large and heavy pile of dirt" (deep inside the earth).

Comment: that is mean lower temperature is more favourable than higher temperature for synthesis of diamond at this range of pressure , right ?

or it mean the diamond produced will be not stable ?!

sorry, but I can't compeletly understand.

Comment: It says that at lower temperature, diamond is more stable than graphite at lower pressure. This does not tell you about the rate at which one turns into the other - that is a very difficult calculation (because of the metastable state).